# How do the load and the second stage amplifier affect output/input impedances of a bjt multistage amplifier

Tags: amplifier, bjt

It is easy to show that the Output and input impedance are in a mathematical relation, but it is not clear to me how that is possible. How is the load positioned at one end of the amplifier able to affect the input impedance which is on the other end of the circuit?

Comment: Draw a circuit.

Comment: People will probably answer this question, but if you don't draw a circuit, they will probably not answer the question in a way that is helpful to you. So, as Andy said, draw a circuit.

Comment: Base current and Miller capacitance. NFB in some topologies.

Comment: Yes - this may happen. However, the amount how much the output conditions will influence the input properties of an amplifier depends on retroactive effects - and these are very different for the various active elements. Therefore, we need a circuit diagram.